# Is partial amount allowed to be converted/rolled over from traditional to roth-IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira

Say a person has $50,000 in his/her traditional IRA account. Now due to
Now he wants to transfer part of it say $10,000 into a roth-IRA account. Is such a partial roll over to roth-IRA possible?
Also the person only has to pay taxes on the $10,000 he/she is transferring/rolling over to roth-IRA right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can convert as little as you want to a Roth IRA, all the way up to the entire account value. At most you would owe regular income tax on the full amount you convert; less if you made non-deductible contributions.

Also note that you don't need to call it a "backdoor" conversion, particularly if it's taxable. It's just a standard Roth conversion.

Comment: thanks for the clarification Craig. Just to follow up on your comment on the backdoor-ira; Is backdoor roth-IRA the one where someone converts a 401K into a roth-IRA via a traditional IRA? Thank you.

Comment: @adi It's not an official term but a "backdoor Roth IRA contribution" is when you make a non-deductible traditional IRA contribution and convert to Roth soon afterward. Additionally you could call it a "backdoor Roth conversion" when the conversion is primarily non-taxable.

Comment: Craig, you mentioned `conversion is primarily non-taxable.`. What is the scenario wherein any conversion to roth-IRA can be non-taxable? As far as I know both conversion of 401K directly to roth-IRA  and traditional to roth-IRA have tax consequences.

Comment: @adi When you make a non-deductible traditional IRA contribution, and then immediately convert, it will be 100% (or very nearly) non-taxable.